# Overwriting a row with a matched ID value in the same dataframe

Tags: r

I have an odd issue I just haven't been able to find a good solution to. Basically, our system outputs scores for people, *usually* only the first time they are in the system. However, sometimes it enters the scores the second time they are in the system, and sometimes it fills all rows like it should. Correcting the database would be ideal but that isn't going to happen (thanks management). We also can't just get rid of duplicate ID values as they are duplicated for a reason. What I need to do is copy the scores into the fields that have NA for all matching ID values. So, here is a data example:

```
ID  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3  VAR4  VAR5
1  16  15  14  15  46
1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2  15  12  11  14  12
3  14  12  12  15  22
3  14  12  12  15  22
4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4  11  04  12  33  12
6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

The output would look like

```
ID  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3  VAR4  VAR5
1  16  15  14  15  46
1  16  15  14  15  46
2  15  12  11  14  12
3  14  12  12  15  22
3  14  12  12  15  22
4  11  04  12  33  12
4  11  04  12  33  12
6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I managed to get something working for this problem in order to move it off my desk, but this problem is going to be reoccuring and I want a better solution. My solution is:

```
df_2 <- list()
for(i in df$ID){
  filter(df, ID == i) %>%
    mutate(VAR1 = mean(VAR1, na.rm = TRUE),
           VAR2 = mean(VAR2, na.rm = TRUE),
           VAR3 = mean(VAR3, na.rm = TRUE),
           VAR4 = mean(VAR4, na.rm = TRUE),
           VAR5 = mean(VAR5, na.rm = TRUE))
} -> df_2[[i]]

# Then we bind this together as a dataframe
bind_rows(df_2) -> df_replaced

# Remove the list object as it's huge
rm(df_2)
```

This works but it takes about a thousand years and creates a temporary list around 4 gigs (df_2). Which is why I need to remove it as soon as possible because it pretty much brings my system to a complete halt. I feel like there is something with match but I'm not really sure how to intelligently select data row to copy over NA row.

EDIT: Fixed table formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R method using `is.na` and `match` to select the indices to use as fillers and to be filled.

```
df[is.na(df$VAR1), -1] <- df[match(df$ID[is.na(df$VAR1)],
                                   df$ID[ifelse(!is.na(df$VAR1), TRUE, NA)]), -1]
```

which returns

```
df
  ID VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5
1  1   16   15   14   15   46
2  1   16   15   14   15   46
3  2   15   12   11   14   12
4  3   14   12   12   15   22
5  3   14   12   12   15   22
6  4   11    4   12   33   12
7  4   11    4   12   33   12
8  6   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

The trick here is to use `ifelse` to return a table (the second argument to `match`) that is the same length as the number of rows in the data.frame.