# Comparation between elements in two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I'd like to compare the elements `a1` in `df1` to `a2` in `df2` and put on element of `b1` in `b2`. For example, `df1[2, 1] == df2[3,1]` then, `df2[3,1] <- df1[2,1]`.

```
set.seed(1)
a1 <- letters
b1 <- rnorm(length(a1))

a2 <- sample(letters, 26, replace = T)
b2 <- rep(0, length(a1))

df1 <- data.frame(a1, b1)
df2 <- data.frame(a2, b2)
```

OBS.: This question is different of [MATCH function in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170574/match-function-in-r).
In my question, the data frame `df1` presents only one kind of letters, but `df2` presents repeated letters.

Comment: You have data frames not matrices. And what is the output in case if df1 != df2?

Comment: The answer was given by <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right>, thanks.